# Importing a future membership start date: Invalid value for field(s) : Start Date 01/25/2021

Tags: civimember, import

I get the above statement when I try to import a membership. I have coded the date in different ways, and eventhough the fields match with my definition I get the same answer. Really I wonder why this field is mandatory and my import fail as a consequence. Can anyone help? I have already registered the Contact so this is step two.

Comment: Just curiosity, when you look at the csv in a text editor of some sort, what does the date value look like? Perhaps converting the date field to text, ensuring it remains as 'yyyymmdd' etc would help?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I believe that the fallout was that the date was set to tomorrow, instad of today or yestertime. The fault message was therefore unclear!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the date format you have selected on Import Membership form when you try to upload the import file

[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me! Well,I hoped I had clearly described that I had matched the date styles, and still it does not work! I tried several different, and the registration still does not work. I can supet that I made another mistake, and the error message might not be too clear. The otters two imports, Contribution and Contact work well as the need for date is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment Claes Rickeby, you can setup an custom membership status of "Upcoming". This is an example:

[image]